# java: Convert a string which represents a two digit year to four digits

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

This question has been asked many times but I have an issue which I feel makes it a unique question.

Here it goes.

I have a string which represents a two digit year i.e. to write 2016 I input 16

I have a requirement to convert a two digit year to four digit year i.e. 16 becomes 2016.

After going through some questions and answers I made the following findings

**Solution 1**

```
DateFormat sdfp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yy");
Date d = sdfp.parse(input);
DateFormat sdff = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdff.format(d);
```

This would be great but I do not have a month or day in my case just a year and I could not find a way to create a date object with just the year.

**Solution 2**

The above could be solved with a `Calendar` object but it does not allow the input an of a two digit year for its year field.

**Edit**
Forgot to mention I cannot use Joda-Time because I'm working on the Android platform and it would increase the size of my project for just this small use

Comment: If you need to use a date object specifically, I believe there is a short date format for just year. If not, you could just let this default to whatever and then always just display it in a short string of the year only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just remove the part of month and day from the format?

```
DateFormat sdfp = new SimpleDateFormat("yy");
Date d = sdfp.parse(input);
DateFormat sdff = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String date = sdff.format(d);
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/CJR34170)

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is the rule about how `SimpleDateFormat` interpret the abbreviated year. (bold by me)

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"), `SimpleDateFormat` must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some century. It does this by adjusting dates to be **within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the `SimpleDateFormat` instance is created**. For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a `SimpleDateFormat` instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be interpreted as May 4, 1964.

Comment: As it turns out OP plans to use the code for more than a hundred years, I don't think this solution is "scalable" It will work for short periods of time, but when it'll need to deal with older data (-20 years) which makes sense for an app that will work for 80+ years, it will not work as expected

Comment: That means it would give us up to 2036 and then jumps to 1937 for 37 as input string. What about "100" as an input.

Comment: @Scitech, no that would be relatively a good case, 'cause you would know what to expect. But according to the yellow paragraph, it depends on when the SimpleDateFormat object was created... so you don't really know anything

Comment: @Gavriel right!  any alternative to `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @Gavriel Android probably won't even exist in 80 years.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is much simpler:

```
String year = "20" + input;
```

But if you want to make the user's life easy, and assume that he's entering a valid card, this problem is easy: if he types in 2 digits, then add (thisYear/100). If this seems to be in the past in the past, then if it's more than 90 years in the past, then add another 100 (this will only be the case in the last decade of any century)

```
Date now = new Date();
int expYear = (int)(now.getYear()/100) + parseInt(input);
if (expYear < now.getYear() && expYear+90<now.getYear()) {
    expYear += 100;
}
```

Comment: Aye, this is the solution but the app would break in the year 2100 :D

Comment: Of course it would. But how would you try to express the year 2116 with two digits without confusing it with 2016?

Comment: That's why no sane programmer would accept a two digit year nowadays.

Comment: @ErsenOsmanm if you plan your app to work after 2100, then PLEASE don't use 2 digits for year!!!!!!!

Comment: @Tom It is for a card expiry year.

Comment: @Gavriel haha I will be a brain in a jar by that time :)

Comment: I think this is an adequate solution since it is for an Android application. No Android application written now will still be in use by 2100. Either Android will have evolved, the app would have been updated (for design if not functionality), or replaced by a new technology.

Comment: @ErsenOsman, just out of curiosity, where do these 2 digits come from? I know it is printed on the cards, but when you talk to any apis of any bank I know of, they have a proper 4 digit format, so if I were you, I would make the user input 4 digits (that will be OK for another 7984 years :)

Comment: @Gavriel I've made my expiry year take 2 digits and 4 digits so the user has a choice and I cater for both because the Stripe API requires the year to be four digits. Some credit cards have the date in two digit form so I'm attempting to make the user's life easier :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static int adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(int year) {
    return adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(year, Year.now().getValue());
  }

  public static int adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(int inputYear, int referenceYear) {
    if(inputYear > 99) {
      return inputYear;
    }

    int currentCentury = referenceYear / 100 * 100;
    int currentCenturyYear = currentCentury + inputYear;
    int upperLimit = referenceYear + 20;
    int lowerLimit = referenceYear - 79;

    // initially place it in current century
    int adjusted = currentCenturyYear;

    if(adjusted> upperLimit) {
      // shift a century down
      adjusted -= 100;
    }
    else if(adjusted < lowerLimit) {
      // shift a century up
      adjusted += 100;
    }

    return adjusted;
  }
```

Some Testing:

```
  @Test
  public void test_adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput()
  {
    assertEquals(2017, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(17, 2017));
    assertEquals(2037, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(37, 2017)); // +20
    assertEquals(1938, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(38, 2017)); // +21
    assertEquals(2000, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(0, 2017)); // 0
    assertEquals(1999, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(99, 2017)); // 99

    assertEquals(2078, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(78, 2078)); 
    assertEquals(2098, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(98, 2078)); // + 20
    assertEquals(1999, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(99, 2078)); // + 21 / 99
    assertEquals(2000, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(0, 2078)); // 0

    assertEquals(1990, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(90, 1990));
    assertEquals(1999, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(99, 1990)); // 99
    assertEquals(2000, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(0, 1990)); // 0
    assertEquals(2010, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(10, 1990)); // +20
    assertEquals(1911, adjustOneOrTwoDigitYearInput(11, 1990)); // +21
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Year from java.time if you are using java 8:

```
Year year = Year.parse("18", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy"));
year.toString(); //This returns 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
String input = "16";
String str = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)).substring(0, 2)+input;
System.out.println("str = " + str);
```

And the result:

```
str = 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple one. Courtesy Gavriel

```
 String year = "20" + input;
if(input>99)
{
String year= "2"+input;
}
```

Comment: oops again! 16 as input can be confused with 2016 and 2116. century issues